# In Java, is there a performance difference between Log and Log10?

Tags: java

I have seen both `Log10(x)` and `Log(x)/Log(10)` used in different programs to calculate a base 10 logarithm. Is there anything about their implementation that makes taking two natural logarithms more or equivalently performant than taking a single base 10 logarithm? The second seems wasteful, provided the desired base is known at compile time.

Comment: Where are you getting these functions? I believe this would be implementation-specific, as `Log10(x)` may be `function Log10(int x) { return Log(x) / Log(10); }`

Comment: There is `Math.log10(x)` already in the JSE. It makes code cleaner & clearer. Anyway, micro optimization won't worth.

Comment: @Zymus nope. Both methods `log` and `log10` end calling native methods.

Comment: in my profiling `log(x)` seems a little faster than `log10(x)`;  `log10(x)` is a little faster than `log(x)/const`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should just use `log10`, which actually ends up calling a native function (i.e. it is not implemented in Java -- see [`StrictMath.log10`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StrictMath.html#log10(double))). `log(x)/log(10)` is likely used by people who don't know about `log10`. You almost certainly will not notice a performance discrepancy between the two variants.

`log10(x)` clearly conveys your intention, whereas with `log(x)/log(10)`, it isn't as clear that you really want a base-10 logarithm.

Comment: Right, using the change of base unnecessarily might be inefficient.

Comment: Here's the [source code for `Math#log(double d)`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Math.java) and here for [StrictMath#log](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/StrictMath.java). I was searching those to provide an answer.

Comment: Is this a little strongly worded: *You almost certainly will not notice a performance discrepancy between the two variants.*? Certainly this is true to get a single log, but some code gets many. One of the variants requires a single native call, and the other requires two native calls. Presumably that can make an observable difference when called many times?

Comment: @AndyThomas Note that because it's dividing by a constant expression, the second native call may actually not be made in runtime, and instead, you get a simple division.

Comment: there appear to be visible performance difference, around 1ns.

Comment: @RealSkeptic - In terms of the Java language, `log(10)` is *not* a [constant expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). I don't happen to know if particular Java compilers know that log(x) is referentially transparent.

Comment: @bayou.io That difference may just be caused by your computer's CPU usage changing between tests.